# How can I set styles for a tag with content specific to another tag with CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I set styles for a tag with content specific to another tag with CSS?

For example I have this:

```
<p>paragraph one</p>
<p>paragraph <span>two</span></p>
<p>paragraph three</p>
```

I just want show "paragraph two" with red color because this `<p>` tag contains a `<span>` tag.

(Only use CSS and don't change HTML.)

Comment: You'll need to use JS if you want to target ones parent. You can't write conditionals like this within CSS

Answer (score 1):

You can't with pure CSS for now : it might be a future spec of CSS4 ([reference](http://www.red-team-design.com/meet-the-css4-selectors)).

However, you can use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) for that, and its [`:has` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) :

```
$('p:has(span)').addClass('red');
```

with css simply looking like :

```
.red{
    color:red;
}
```

See this tiny [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/uPTP9/)